# Blender 2.8 - Wireframed objects not rendering

Tags: wireframe

Must have accidentally gotten into some kind of ghost mode for 2 out of hundreds of objects. They show as black wireframes, are editable, but only show as wireframe in every shading mode, and don't render. Regardless of hide / render settings in the object list to the right. Tried flipping normals, recalculating inside/out, everything..
What happened? How do I get the objects back? Snapshot shows the wireframed objects.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Freaky, somehow "Object/Viewport Display/Display As" was set to "Wire" instead of textured AND all "Cycles Settings/Ray Visibility" were unchecked (for only two objects)! I've never even opened these panels before..